CROP CIRCLES : Looking for an easy way to IMPORT and SCALE vectors in a custom map on Google Maps
The point of the project is to make some crop circles, The objective is to be able to trace a polygon from a map by walking around a field (and using the GPS to be able to see where you are). I need to be able to access the map on my phone and to be able to see in real time my location so was thinking of importing a custom map on Google Maps and using that but open to other ideas.
How can I import a vector (SVG or else) into Google Maps and how could I easily scale it and move it around so I can place it over the field I'm looking to make a circle over?
